# iOS 16 Launch Screen status bar style cannot be changed to light content

Tags: ios, statusbar

I am trying to change my status bar style to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` for my app's launch screen, but it seems that the status bar remains dark no matter which setting I choose in Xcode.

You can see that the status bar style is set to Light Content in the project configuration and `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` in my Info.plist file.

[image: Xcode configuration]

[image: Info Plist]

However, the status bar in the launch screen remains dark as you can see from this GIF:

[image: status bar style]

I am able to reproduce this issue by creating a new project and attempting to change the status bar style. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I'm thinking this is a bug in iOS 16, because in iOS 15 doing what you did works.

Comment: Yes very odd. I can confirm this works on iOS 14 and iOS 15. I filed a bug report (FB11734800).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the info key `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this appears as a suggestion so often when researching this topic. View controller-based status bar appearance has no bearing on the launch screen status bar appearance (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiviewcontrollerbasedstatusbarappearance). Regardless, as a test I set this property to NO and it made no difference. The status bar remains dark.

Comment: I just double checked with a new project. Set to Light Content = no success. Add the `View controller-based...` key set to NO and it works.

Comment: Found this: https://medium.com/@craiggrummitt/the-mysterious-case-of-the-status-bar-d9059a327c97 Might help, might not. Seems to be an overly complicated knot.

Comment: Thanks @Magnas. I am referring to the launch screen, not the initial view controller. If you look carefully at when the app is launching, you will see that the status bar still starts out with dark content. To verify this further, put `sleep(1000);` in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. When you set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES`, you're making it so the initial view controller has a light status bar, but this has no bearing  on the launch screen status bar style.

Comment: Correction - above meant to say when you set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO`

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this is a bug in iOS 16 and It still exists in 2023.7.18

Comment: Has anyone solved it yet?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).